# Variable Changing In Certain Functions, and Not Changing In Certain Functions

Tags: javascript, variables, setinterval

I'm getting really annoyed here. This is my code:

```
var qi = 0;
var value = 0;
var correct = new Audio("correct.mp3");
var lifeline_waiting_sound = new Audio("life.mp3");
var loss = new Audio("loss.mp3");
var hasPass = true;
var fmsgtv;
var currentANS;
var questions = {
    "a": [
        {
            question: "What type of animals only eat meat?",
            val: 100,
            r_answer: 1,
            answers: [
            "Omnivore",
            "Carnivore",
            "Herbivore",
            "All of the above"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Which type of animal mainly gives live birth?",
            val: 200,
            r_answer: 0,
            answers: [
            "Mammals",
            "Reptiles",
            "Amphibians",
            "Birds"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "These mammals lays eggs.",
            val: 300,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Humans",
            "Hippos",
            "Platypuses",
            "Hamsters"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Which of these terms mean warm-blooded?",
            val: 500,
            r_answer: 1,
            answers: [
            "Ectothermic",
            "Endothermic",
            "Both of the Above",
            "None of the Above"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Fish have a _ bladder.",
            val: 1000,
            r_answer: 3,
            answers: [
            "Lateral",
            "Afloat",
            "Cartilage",
            "Swim"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Which types of vertabrates have thin, moist skin?",
            val: 2000,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Reptiles",
            "Mammals",
            "Amphibians",
            "Birds"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "What was the first group of fish to ever evolve?",
            val: 4000,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Bony",
            "Cartilaginous", 
            "Jawless",
            "All of the above"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Which of these animals have the longest gestation period?",
            val: 8000,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Dog",
            "Human",
            "Alpaca",
            "Lion"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "What are nares?",
            val: 16000,
            r_answer: 0,
            answers: [
            "Nostrils",
            "A Part of the Lungs",
            "Little Bones in the Ear",
            "Toes"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "There are over/about _____ species of fish in the world.",
            val: 32000,
            r_answer: 1,
            answers: [
            "99,999",
            "34000",
            "27000",
            "41000"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "What are the 3 orders of amphibians?",
            val: 64000,
            r_answer: 3,
            answers: [
            "Anura, Prototheria, Osteichthyes",
            "Metatheria, Eutheria, Apoda",
            "Placentals, Squamata, Crocodylia",
            "Anura, Caudata, Apoda"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "What habitats do reptiles NOT live in?",
            val: 125000,
            r_answer: 0,
            answers: [
            "Tundra, Polar Ice",
            "Polar Ice, Desert",
            "Seasonal Forest, Ocean",
            "None of the above (they live in all of them)"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Primitive Fish date back how far?",
            val: 250000,
            r_answer: 1,
            answers: [
            "475 Million Years",
            "550 Million Years",
            "750 Million Years",
            "300 Million Years"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "What group of animals have a two chambered heart?",
            val: 500000,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Reptiles",
            "Amphibians",
            "Fish",
            "Mammals"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "d":[
        {
            question: `What kind of eggs are these? <br><img src='https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.76877a36d3ea95356ed01edb0757b4a3?rik=wZOPeN8W1ceKVA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fvoice.gardenbird.co.uk%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2017%2f03%2fBlackbird-Eggs.jpg&ehk=LtJAYsynWLJDm5qUul%2bVg7ShYJk243%2fhDJ2H0rxDWCU%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0'
            style='width: 8.3vw; position: absolute; border-radius: 30.3vw; left: 34.3vw'>`,
            val: 100,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Fish Eggs",
            "Amphibian Eggs",
            "Bird Eggs",
            "Mammal/Platypuses' Eggs"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Axolotys are _______________.",
            val: 200,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Mammals",
            "Fish",
            "Amphibians",
            "Birds"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Birds have hollow bones because _____________________________.",
            val: 300,
            r_answer: 1,
            answers: [
            "they want to be cool",
            "it helps them fly",
            "it makes their transition into a bird to a tree faster",
            "it helps them walk on land"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Birds have _______________.",
            val: 500,
            r_answer: 0,
            answers: [
            "no teeth",
            "3 sets of teeth",
            "sharp teeth",
            "dull teeth"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Bison can fly.",
            val: 1000,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "That statement is true.",
            "There is a minority that doesn't.",
            "That statement is false.",
            "Scientists don't know yet"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "All variables have ________.",
            val: 2000,
            r_answer: 3,
            answers: [
            "a backbone",
            "no backbone",
            "the ability to speak",
            "None Of The Above"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "What is gestation?",
            val: 4000,
            r_answer: 3,
            answers: [
            "<span style='font-size: 1.63vw;'>the period in which an animal is drastically changing/evolving</span>",
            "<span style='font-size: 1.63vw;'>the classification of a vertebrate based on it's habitat</span>", 
            "<span style='font-size: 1.63vw;'>the period in which a species population is rapidly declining</span>",
            "<span style='font-size: 1.63vw;'>the period from conception to the birth of an organism</span>"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Which of these animals have the longest gestation period?",
            val: 8000,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Dog",
            "Human",
            "Alpaca",
            "Lion"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Vertebrata is a ___________________.",
            val: 16000,
            r_answer: 1,
            answers: [
            "Domain",
            "Sub Phylum",
            "Sub Species",
            "Genus"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "What is the scientific name for a bird?",
            val: 32000,
            r_answer: 0,
            answers: [
            "Aves",
            "Angularasaurus",
            "Birdauta",
            "Ctheodta"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Lizards are ____________.",
            val: 64000,
            r_answer: 2,
            answers: [
            "Mammals",
            "Amphibians",
            "Reptiles",
            "Not A Vertebrate"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Which of these animals do exist?",
            val: 125000,
            r_answer: 0,
            answers: [
            "Transparent Metallic Bird",
            "Flying Squirrel",
            "Desert Dolphin",
            "Human-Frog Snake Axolotl"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "Amphibians are __________.",
            val: 250000,
            r_answer: 1,
            answers: [
            "Omnivore",
            "Carnivore",
            "Herbivore",
            "All of the above"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "What is cutaneous breathing?",
            val: 500000,
            r_answer: 0,
            answers: [
            "<span style='font-size: 1.63vw;'>the ability to breath through skin</span>",
            "<span style='font-size: 1.63vw;'>the ability to breath both underwater and on land</span>",
            "<span style='font-size: 1.63vw;'>the ability to prevent breathing for up to 9 days</span>",
            "<span style='font-size: 1.63vw;'>the ability to safely inhale carbon-dioxide</span>"
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "<span style='color: gold;'>MILLION DOLLAR QUESTION</span><br>Which of these are NOT an actual phylum of fish?",
            val: 1000000,
            r_answer: 3,
            answers: [
            "Perciformes",
            "Sphymidae",
            "Siluriformes",
            "Phantaciuformes"
            ]
        },
    ]
}

var findAnswer = {
    r: function(){
        console.log(qi);
        return questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].r_answer;
    },
    randomA:function(){
        /*var ranD = Math.floor(Math.random * 2) + 1;
        ranD2 = Math.floor(Math.random * 3);
        var final;
        if (ranD==1) {
           return  questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].r_answer
        } else {
            while(true){
                if(!(ranD2==questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].r_answer)){
                    final=questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[ranD2];
                    console.log("wrong");
                    return questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[ranD2];
                } else {
                    ranD2=Math.floor(Math.random * 3)
                    console.log("right")
                }
            } 
        }*/
    },
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    localStorage.setItem("qi", qi)
    document.querySelector("[question]").innerHTML = questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].question;
    document.querySelector("[ans='a']").innerHTML = "A. &#8194;" + questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[0];
    document.querySelector("[ans='b']").innerHTML = "B. &#8194;" + questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[1];
    document.querySelector("[ans='c']").innerHTML = "C. &#8194;" + questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[2];
    document.querySelector("[ans='d']").innerHTML = "D. &#8194;" + questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[3];
    for(let i = 0;i < document.querySelectorAll("[value]").length; i++){
        if(document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].getAttribute("value")==questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].val){
            document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].style.color = "red";
        }
    }
})

function checkAnswer(elem){
    document.querySelector("[coi]").innerHTML = "----";
    document.querySelector("[coi]").style.color = "white";
    if(an.n==questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].r_answer){
        document.querySelector("[valdec]").innerHTML = "";
        document.querySelector("[c_ans]").style.display = "block";
        correct.volume = 0.1;
        setTimeout(function(){
            correct.play()
        }, 1500)
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector("[coi]").innerHTML = "correct!";
            document.querySelector("[coi]").style.color = "green";
            value=questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].val;
            document.querySelector("[valdec]").innerHTML = "Your team now has $" + value + ".";
            document.querySelector("[money_amount]").innerHTML = "$" + value;
            for(let i = 0;i < document.querySelectorAll("[value]").length; i++){
                if(document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].getAttribute("value")==questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].val){
                    document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].style.color = "black";
                    document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(grey, black)";
                }
            }
        }, 2000)
    } else {
        document.querySelector("[valdec]").innerHTML = "";
        document.querySelector("[c_ans]").style.display = "block";
        correct.volume = 0.1;
        setTimeout(function(){
            loss.play()
        }, 1000)
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector("[coi]").innerHTML = "incorrect!";
            document.querySelector("[coi]").style.color = "red";
            value=questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].val;
            if(hasPass){
                document.querySelector("[valdec]").innerHTML = "Sorry! You still have a pass. Do you want to use it?";
                setTimeout(function(){
                    hasPass = false;
                }, 100)
            } else {
                document.querySelector("[valdec]").innerHTML = "You're team has no more passes, so unfortunately, that's it.";
            }
            for(let i = 0;i < document.querySelectorAll("[value]").length; i++){
                if(document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].getAttribute("value")==questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].val){
                    document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].style.color = "black";
                    document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(grey, black)";
                }
            }
        }, 3000)
    }
}
function newQuestion(){
    qi++
    localStorage.setItem("qi", qi)
    document.querySelector("[c_ans]").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("[question]").innerHTML = questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].question;
    document.querySelector("[ans='a']").innerHTML = "A. &#8194;" + questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[0];
    document.querySelector("[ans='b']").innerHTML = "B. &#8194;" + questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[1];
    document.querySelector("[ans='c']").innerHTML = "C. &#8194;" + questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[2];
    document.querySelector("[ans='d']").innerHTML = "D. &#8194;" + questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[3];
    document.querySelector("[ans='a']").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(69, 69, 148, 0.61)";
    document.querySelector("[ans='b']").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(69, 69, 148, 0.61)";
    document.querySelector("[ans='c']").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(69, 69, 148, 0.61)";
    document.querySelector("[ans='d']").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(69, 69, 148, 0.61)";
    for(let i = 0;i < document.querySelectorAll("[value]").length; i++){
        if(document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].getAttribute("value")==questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].val){
            document.querySelectorAll("[value]")[i].style.color = "red";
        }
    }
}

function opL(){
    document.querySelector("[cll]").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("[lhdtual]").innerHTML = document.querySelector("[inp]").value + " Has Decided To Use A Lifeline";
    lifeline_waiting_sound.currentTime = 0;
    lifeline_waiting_sound.play()
}

function startMSG(index){
    lifeline_waiting_sound.pause()
    document.querySelector("[msghldr]").innerHTML = "";
    document.querySelector("[msgs]").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("[msginpt]").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("[msginpt]").value=""
    var msg = document.createElement("div");
    msg.setAttribute("msg", "0");
    msg.innerHTML = ".";
    document.querySelector("[msghldr]").appendChild(msg);
    setTimeout(function(){
        msg.innerHTML = "..";
        document.querySelector("[msgdn]").innerHTML = lifelines[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][localStorage.getItem("sel_lfln")].tname;
    }, 500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        msg.innerHTML = "...";
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        pname = "Personsada";
        msg.innerHTML = "....";
    }, 1500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        msg.innerHTML = lifelines[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][localStorage.getItem("sel_lfln")].intmes;
    }, 2000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector("[msginpt]").style.display = "block";
    }, 7000)
    document.querySelector("[questMSGBX]").innerHTML = questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].question;
    document.querySelector("[anslist]").innerHTML = `
        <li>${questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[0]}</li>
        <li>${questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[1]}</li>
        <li>${questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[2]}</li>
        <li>${questions[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][qi].answers[3]}</li>
    `;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //startMSG()
})

function submitMessageTwo(){
    var msg2 = document.createElement("div");
    msg2.setAttribute("msg", "1");
    msg2.innerHTML = document.querySelector("[msginpt]").value;
    msg2.style.top = ((parseInt(lifelines[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][localStorage.getItem("sel_lfln")].intmes.split("").length)/31)*1.83+4.3).toString() + "vw";
    fmsgtv = ((parseInt(lifelines[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][localStorage.getItem("sel_lfln")].intmes.split("").length)/31)*1.83+4.3);
    document.querySelector("[msghldr]").appendChild(msg2);
    setTimeout(function(){
        responseMSG()
    }, 2000)
}

function responseMSG(){
    var msg12 = document.createElement("div");
    msg12.setAttribute("msg", "0");
    msg12.innerHTML = "";
    msg12.style.top = (fmsgtv+18.3).toString() + "vw";
    msg12.style.position = "fixed";
    document.querySelector("[msghldr]").appendChild(msg12);
    msg12.style.width = "9.3vw";
    setTimeout(function(){
        msg12.style.width = "26.3vw";
    }, 200)
    setTimeout(function(){
        msg12.innerHTML = lifelines[localStorage.getItem("current_team")][localStorage.getItem("sel_lfln")].respnmes;
    }, 1500)
    console.log(qi + "this")
}
```

So in the HTML file there is a button, when you press it, the variable qi goes up. Then, in another JS file, when commanded to, text is put on the document that includes the use of findAnswer.r(); But whenever that returns whatever it returns, it treats qi as if it's value is still 0. Can anyone find any errors in my code? Visual Studio Code isn't giving me any errors, or the console on the document, so I'm very confused.

I tried using setInterval to constantly check what the value of qi was, and it went up every time the button was clicked, but when the text was set to go on the screen with findAnswer.r() I made it console.log() what qi was, and it said 0;
I also tried making an array, and I made an interval where it constantly changes the array to `----[qi].answers` . Then I made it also log the array, and it said the array was empty. And like I said, all the other things qi is used in like `checkAnswer()` are fine. And it's the same variable in the same document too.